Is it okay for a male to wear bracelets/necklaces with sparkly rainbow beads in college?
Is it okay for a male to wear bracelets/necklaces with sparkly rainbow beads in college? Asking this because this is normally what girls wear, so that it is often perceived that it is likely LGBT(Q)-supportive for boys wearing jewelry of these colors.

This is a) probably not on-topic for this stack forum, and b) so wildly dependent upon location/other factors that you are not likely to get a good answer here. In undergraduate classes/courses in many universities in the US, students are well-dressed if they wear something other than sweat pants/pajama pants to class and no one is going to care what jewelry a student wears. A graduate program in the middle east might have extremely different opinions on the topic.

Asking this because it is about dress code & professional ethics in college, as part of academia

This wouldn't be professional ethics. Regardless, you are very definitely going to need to supply a location. Whether the college in question is private or public is also a huge factor. Is this graduate or undergraduate level? Is the worry that fellow students will see the beads and assume you are LGBT(Q) supportive when you don't want them to make that assumption (for whatever reason)? Or that you don't want them to assume that you are a member of the LGBT(Q) community? Or that you're worried that gaudy jewelry will be seen as a distraction/unprofessional, regardless of LGBT(Q) connotations?

Sorry, questions about "undergraduate life or culture" are off-topic. Even beyond that, you would need to tell us what part of the world you are in and what you mean by "okay" -- what your peers consider okay will likely be different than the faculty.

One begins to wonder about some things here. Eigrp four, have fun with it!

In the US it is fine. Same for many other countries. There are places where it wouldn’t be safe however, but I assume you aren’t in Afghanistan or somewhere else with morality police that have life and death authority over citizens.
It isn't an issue of ethics, or even etiquette in the parts of the world considered modern or liberal, but you can find haters everywhere.
Moreover, college should be a safe place for those with unconventional views, though that shouldn't be a description for LGBTQ+ support.
If you are in a place where this would be "frowned" upon or you would be attacked for it or looked down upon, consider it a personal safety issue.

Note that while this is a possibly off topic question for this site, I consider the advice to the OP to be important enough to make an exception, based on the personal safety aspect. I hope you, and the moderators, agree.

Not every place in the US is the same either. I wonder how that would go over at, say, Liberty University.

@WolfgangBangerth, probably not so well, but I'd guess a student or faculty member there wouldn't ask such a question. And, they do seem to have "morality" police.
